# mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'

Tags: mysql, linux, aws

¿Alguna vez se ha topado con este error "mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF" al momento de realizar una exportación de una base de datos?

Bueno tengo este problema para exportar una base de datos en la terminal linux, estoy menejando AWS, he leído varias notas en esta plataforma pero aun no lo soluciono

¿Alguna solución que me recomienden hacer? es la primera vez que publico una duda en esta plataforma, gracias por su atención y tomarse la molestia de leer esta duda.

Saludooos!

.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Estuve leyendo varias notas pero no me funcionaban y entonces hice lo siguiente:

Este es el comando en donde marcaba el error

```
mysqldump -h "endpoint"-u usuario -p basededatos --set-gtid-purged=OFF > nombredelaexportacion.sql
```

Y este es el comando que me ayudo a solucionarlo:

**Exportar:**

```
mysqldump -h "endpoint" -u usuario -p basededatos > nombredelaexportacion.sql
```

**Importar:**

```
mysql -h "endpoint" -u usuario -p basededatos < nombredelaexportacion.sql
```